# What kind of spider is this?

Tags: species-identification

This large white spider has made her home on our garage. We live in the upper peninsula of Michigan. I believe it's an orb spider but couldn't find any with the large black almost hourglass shape on the back[image]

Comment: A creepy one... Is that a good answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably *[Araneus marmoreus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Araneus_marmoreus)* var. *pyramidatus*.

Here is a better image for comparison:

[image]

<sup>Source: http://www.uksafari.com/marbled_orb_weavers.htm</sup>

PS: Despite *A. marmoreus* being found in US, this variety (*pyramidatus*) is  normally an European one. I don't know any observation of it in US. However, I'll leave this answer here until another ID is provided.

Comment: That is exactly what it looks like. I wonder how she found her way to upper Michigan? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @DorothyRStacy well, the species does exist in US. Your specimen is probably just an individual that resembles that European variety. Anyway, I'm a person that doesn't like to use the terms *variety* or *subspecies*, which for me have no taxonomic meaning.